# How do I overload operator > for scoped enum?

Tags: c++, enums, operators

The following code causes an ambiguous overload error for operator `>`:

```
enum class MyEnum {first, second};
bool operator > (MyEnum lhs, MyEnum rhs)
{
   return static_cast<uint32_t>(lhs) > static_cast<uint32_t>(rhs);
}
MyEnum e1, e2;
auto result = e1 > e2;
```

Can I overload operator `>` for scoped enums? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please help us to help you and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the error with VS2015. Yet I don't see why you create a custom operator and not use the build in one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class MyEnum { first, second };
//bool operator > (MyEnum lhs, MyEnum rhs)
//{
//  return static_cast<uint32_t>(lhs) > static_cast<uint32_t>(rhs);
//}

int main()
{
    MyEnum e1 = MyEnum::first, e2 = MyEnum::second;
    auto result = e1 > e2;
}
```

The code also compiles with GCC 4.9.2 (C++14): http://goo.gl/kpRp1v

Comment: Sorry, I thought the compiler couldn't find the built in operator meaning I had to cast to an integer but trying it again it worked fine.

Really grateful for such a quick response. Sorry for wasting your time.